# Uploading file from Access to SQL Server with DAO code - Object Required error

Tags: sql-server-2008, dao, ms-access-2016

I have an Access 2016 database being used as the frontend for a SQL Server 2008 Express instance. The `WATER_FILES` table exists in the SQL Server database and includes a column `Binary_File` of type `varbinary(MAX)`.

I'm attempting to write a VBA sub routine that will upload a file into that column. The following code causes an error

> Object Required

at runtime. This code is based on this incomplete page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/work-with-attachments-in-dao#

What am I missing?

```
Dim dbsGMEC As DAO.Database
Dim rstWater_Files As DAO.Recordset

Set dbsGMEC = CurrentDb
Set rstWater_Files = dbsGMEC.OpenRecordset("dbo_WATER_FILES", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

'   Unclear if a single record should be opened
'    Dim strSQL As String
'    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo_WATER_FILES WHERE OBJECTID = '2'"
'    Set rstWater_Files = dbsGMEC.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

' Activate edit mode.
rstWater_Files.Edit

' Instantiate the child recordset.
Dim rstFiles As DAO.Recordset

' THIS LINE GIVES THE ERROR "Runtime Error '424': Object Required"
Set rstFiles = rstWater_Files.Fields("Binary_File").Value

' Add a new attachment.
rstFiles.AddNew
rstFiles.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile "C:\test.jpg"
rstFiles.Update

' Update the parent record
rstWater_Files.Update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Set` keyword is used for setting a variable to an object reference. Your `.Value` isn't an object, it's Null. Hence the *Object Required* error.

The code you've found is used for Access attachment fields. `Varbinary(Max)`, however, is not an attachment field, but maps to an OLE object in Access/DAO. That means you need to set the value to a bytearray containing the file data, instead of using a nested recordset to manage attachments.

There are many ways to load a file into a bytearray. I prefer the following code, that uses an `ADODB.Stream` object.

```vb
Dim dbsGMEC As DAO.Database
Dim rstWater_Files As DAO.Recordset

Set dbsGMEC = CurrentDb
Set rstWater_Files = dbsGMEC.OpenRecordset("dbo_WATER_FILES", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
rstWater_Files.Edit
Dim strm As Object
Set strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
strm.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
strm.Open
strm.LoadFromFile "C:\test.jpg"
rstWater_Files.Fields("Binary_File").Value = strm.Read
strm.Close
rstWater_Files.Update
```

To store it back to a file:

```vb
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    .Open
    .Write rstWater_Files.Fields("Binary_File").Value
    .SaveToFile "C:\testcopy.jpg", 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
    .Close
End With
```

If you really don't like `ADODB`, and even the thought of an `ADODB.Stream` disgusts you, you can also use VBA itself to read a file into a bytearray:

```vb
Dim dbsGMEC As DAO.Database
Dim rstWater_Files As DAO.Recordset

Set dbsGMEC = CurrentDb
Set rstWater_Files = dbsGMEC.OpenRecordset("dbo_WATER_FILES", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
rstWater_Files.Edit
Dim byteArr() As Byte
Dim fileInt As Integer: fileInt = FreeFile
Open "C:\test.jpg" For Binary Access Read As #fileInt
ReDim byteArr(0 To LOF(fileInt) - 1)
Get #fileInt, , byteArr
Close #fileInt
rstWater_Files.Fields("Binary_File").Value = byteArr
rstWater_Files.Update
```

This last code will cap the max file size of 2,147,483,647 bytes (the max size of a Long). However, this is also the max size of an Access database, so you'll likely run into trouble before that. This code also doesn't use chunking, so it might use more memory than required.

Comment: Thanks Erik! The ADODB stream approach worked fine. I really appreciate your guidance. I'm now trying to write the contents of the file out using SaveToFile... Any recommendation on how to correctly open the recordset, record, stream (and field)?? I haven't found an example of these methods for ADODB objects and writing to the filesystem. Or do you prefer a different approach?
Lastly, yes or no question - can the file contents be output in an Access report? E.g. populate a template with file?

Comment: I've provided an example of how to write back the content using an `ADODB.Stream`. Like `.LoadFromFile`, `.SaveToFile` is for Access attachment fields only. Depending on the exact file type, it can be shown on a report, but often, it's easier to save it to a temporary file and use that.

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much Erik! You're a boss.

Comment: Upvote from me. How I can save file with same name stored to database. `.SaveToFile "C:\testcopy.jpg", 2` How I will replave `testcopy` with stored file name.

Comment: Well, that depends on how you stored that filename. If you have it in a string variable, just use that variable instead of `"C:\testcopy.jpg"`. In contrast to the Access attachment type, blobs don't necessarily include a file name, so it needs to be stored separately somewhere.